# Understanding how linux openssl passwords work

Tags: hash, linux, algorithm

I'm trying to understand how Linux hashes their passwords, so to get started lets say I do this `openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz test`. This will output: `$1$xyz$jAlmRpcFe.aiPOIXET9GG/`. Now what I do understand:

- `$1$` is the `md5` algorithm
- `xyz$` is the salt used with a `$` sign appended to it
- `jAlmRpcFe.aiPOIXET9GG/` is the actual password hashed with `md5` and something else.

The last part is what I do not understand, what else is this hashed computed with?

Comment: It's hashed with the salt. That's what it's for

Comment: ^^ Too bad you can't Accept a comment.

Comment: @Beat that doesn't explain how they get to the `base64` encoded string. If I hashed the salt with the password I'd get something that looks like this: `c1c04d145fb30e2203943ea4f6fed1d4` now if I encode it to `base64`: `YzFjMDRkMTQ1ZmIzMGUyMjAzOTQzZWE0ZjZmZWQxZDQ=` it's not the same thing..

Answer (score 3):

[As wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29#MD5-based_scheme)

> Poul-Henning Kamp designed a baroque and (at the time) computationally expensive algorithm based on the MD5 message digest algorithm.  ...
>   First the passphrase and salt are hashed together, yielding an MD5 message digest. Then a new digest is constructed, hashing together the passphrase, the salt, and the first digest, all in a rather complex form. Then this digest is passed through a thousand iterations of a function which rehashes it together with the passphrase and salt in a manner that varies between rounds. The output of the last of these rounds is the resulting passphrase hash.

That's tells you it's not just doing a (single) hash of pw+salt, but it isn't very exact. Fortunately OpenSSL is open source, so https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/passwd.c#L322 (or apps/passwd.c in any copy of any version of the source which has been available for decades) shows you the exact algorithm. It is indeed baroque, more so than I care to try to explain unless you have a specific question about it.